# "To orange" and "to pink"

Tags: verbs

Are the verbs *to orange* and *to pink* with the meaning "become/turn orange/pink" in everyday use in British or American English?

Comment: Never heard *orange* used as a verb; *pink* has a couple of different meanings as a verb. Although both could be used as verbs, neither is in everyday use in American English, at least.

Comment: What do you use instead? The perifrastic become/turn construction?

Comment: Note that Wiktionary has an entry for [*orange* as a verb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orange#Verb) with quoted texts; however, none of the major dictionaries seem to support this usage. It's definitely uncommon and a typical reader or listener may find it awkward (I certainly do).

Comment: To answer the question a bit more directly, they are not in everyday use. Phrases like "the sun-god liked to orange the sky" or "she oranged her fingernails" are almost nonsensical.

Comment: Something I just noticed: all the color verbs can be intransitive, except *blue*.  You can blue metal or things made of metal, but while something can pinken, blacken, whiten, red, or green, it only *turns* blue.  Then there's the [reflexive case](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BznwsT6r_tM).

Comment: @North: misusing the rules of argument is forgiveable, misspelling the unjustified word is not.

Comment: @Robusto: I've heard _orange_ used as a verb once – in the punch line: _"Orange you glad I didn't say banana?"_ ;^)

Comment: @North. Where have you heard or seen these *to orange* or *to pink*?*  I've never been exposed to *orange* as a verb, though *to yellow* is common, for humans it is called *jaundice*.  *To brown* is also a verb.  The only pink verb I can think of is *to pink up*, in reference to color but usually correlating with an overall improvement in well being. Do you have some source for your question, I'm very curious what made you think of this.

Comment: @Mike *to pink* means to cut a zig-zag edge into something, like cloth - hence, *pinking shears*. But it's nothing to do with the colour.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the color, the "become/turn construction" can be avoided as with [*redden*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redden). One can use [*pinken*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pinken) ("to become pink"). However, there is no "*orangen*", so in some cases you will be stuck with the "periphrastic" form.

Comment: We also have *whiten*, *blacken*, *bruise* (a bit of a stretch, "to turn black and blue"), *[green](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/green)*, *[silverize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/silverize)* and no doubt many more.

Answer (score 1):

British English:

*orange* — I can't find a reference to a verb, and I've never heard it so used.
*pink* — several uses as a verb. ODO lists the following:
[1.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pink) Become pink, perhaps particularly by blushing
[3.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pink--3) Cut with a zigzag edge [using *pinking shears*]
[5.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pink--5) Rough running caused by pre-ignition of fuel in a car engine

Uses 3 and 5 are quite specialised, 1 rather less so; but none is particularly common. As far as colours are concerned, *become orange* and [*become pink* are more likely to be used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pinken%2Cbecome+pink&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). In fact my iPad spell-checker doesn't like "pinken" at all!

Comment: I don't like "pink" as verb meaning "to turn pink" exactly because of the confusion with the "cut" meanings (either in the sense of "cut slightly" or "cut in a zig-zag").  "Pinken" is perfectly good.  My theory about why "orange" isn't a verb: because things *don't turn orange.*  (Not very often, anyway.)

Comment: Don't know if this is an AmE/BrE thing, but def. 5 is for the word "ping" not "pink", unless you are stuffy from a "code".

Comment: @Jim Comparing the etymologies might be an interesting exercise. BrE is definitely *pink*.

Comment: @Malvolio: Oranges turn orange. :^)  I could see an orange grower saying, "The trees should orange by next month," meaning their current green fruit will shine bright orange in a few weeks or so, but, your point is well-taken, it's certainly not going to be a widely-used verb. OED doesn't even list _orange_ as a verb.

Comment: @J.R. Even though Wiktionary has citations for using [orange as a verb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orange#Verb)?! (I didn't find those, Zairja did ; I'm not changing my answer)

Comment: I just checked again; it's a loooonnnng entry, but I can't find any reference to _orange_ being used as a verb in the OED.  *Pink*, on the other hand, has four separate entries as a verb (not meanings, but entries, with each entry listing multiple meanings).  Of course, only the one that means "to color pink" is pertinent here, since that's what the O.P. is inquiring about, but it doesn't hurt to mention the other verbal usages.